# How to extend a class with events

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, events, extension-methods

I´ve written a library, that is implementing a third party protocol. This protocol is following the publish-subscribe pattern (over MQTT). So basically for every message, I have a publisher method and an event, that is fired when a message of certain type arrives. Now, for my needs, I want to extend this protocol with my own messages. But also, I´ve laid down these two requirements:

- Keep the basic library clean only following the protocol architecture
- Extend somehow the basic library with my own messages, so in code, you can use the original messages along with my own messages in one class.

I am thinking about two options here. First is to use C# extensions methods. The big advantage I see in this option is the ability to use only one class with the standard protocol architecture and in case of need, one can add a reference to the assembly with the extensions and use the extended library with my proprietary messages. No refactoring needed. On the other hand, extensions are only static methods and don´t support events.

The second option I see is to inherit a new class and use the basic library as a base. The huge advantage of this is, that I can do everything I want in the derived class. But if one decides to use the extended library after some coding, the refactoring is needed. Here I was considering to name the inherited class with the same name as the base class, but in a different namespace, so in case of need, one can change the using statement form

```
using Hermes
```

into

```
using Hermes.Extended
```

and everything else should work. But this workaround seems to me somehow dirty.

Can anybody advise me the correct way, how to solve this task? What is the best architecture for this? Is there any other way I am not seeing?

For your reference, I am also providing a snippet from the basic class, that is dealing with one message. The extension in whatever form should do basically the same, only with my own types.

```
public async Task NotificationOnAsync(NotificationSwitch Payload)
{
    await PublishToBroker(String.Format("hermes/feedback/sound/toggleOn"), Payload.ToJSON());
}

private EventHandler<NotificationSwitchEventArgs> _notificationTurnedOn;
private object _notificationTurnedOnLock = new object();

public event EventHandler<NotificationSwitchEventArgs> NotificationTurnedOn
{
    add
    {
        lock (_notificationTurnedOnLock)
        {
            _notificationTurnedOn += value;
            SubscribeTopic("hermes/feedback/sound/toggleOn");
        }
    }

    remove
    {
        lock (_notificationTurnedOnLock)
        {
            _notificationTurnedOn -= value;
            if (_notificationTurnedOn is null) UnsubscribeTopic("hermes/feedback/sound/toggleOn");
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void OnNotificationTurnedOn(NotificationSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    _notificationTurnedOn?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

Thanks.

Jiri

Comment: This topic belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The façade pattern would suit your case.